# mysql like query to get max like

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute query:

```
 ----------------------
|name                  |
 ----------------------
|data                  |
|data get go           |
|data get to go        |
 ----------------------
```

`Select * from table where name like '%data%' or name like '%go%' or name like'%get%';`

Acc. to me out put should me:

```
 ----------------------
|name                  |
 ----------------------
|data get go           |
|data get to go        |
 ----------------------
```

but i get

```
 ----------------------
|name                  |
 ----------------------
|data                  |
|data get go           |
|data get to go        |
 ----------------------
```

Please help me to get correct output.

Comment: That *is* the correct output! All rows include `data`, thus verify your condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first where clause

```
 name like '%data%
```

is going to include that first row.
So change it to

```
Select * from table where name like '%data%' AND (name like '%go%' or name like'%get%');
```

and that should do it. It will make sure data is in the name along with either `go` or `get`

EDIT:

Follow up question...

Kind of hard to understand what you are trying to say. But is it that you want to return the results that have the most words in the name that were in the search? So if I search "1 2 3 4 5",

from 
**_________**
|name            |
|---------------|
|1 2                 |
|1 2 3 4 5   |
|1 2 3            |
|1 2 3 4       |
----------------

You'd want the, top 3 most used. So:

**_________**
|1 2 3 4 5  |
|1 2 3 4      |
|1 2 3          |
-----------------

And it wouldn't return the '1 2' row. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: i want to use this query in search so user is free to type any thing so i have to find mach case.

Comment: Well your current query is correct with the output. If your want to filter certain words from the search, you would need 
    where name NOT LIKE '%EXPLICIT%'

Comment: what does this means.

Comment: You haven't really told us why you don't want the first row returned. Is the name too short? Is it a bad word? Why are you trying to not get that row returned?

Comment: but the is that use can type more text than present in data so i need to find that all max matching words like google do

Comment: no. I will try to explain you with example : let there is a data in mysql table for search `Hello user search` but user didn't know any thing about his data so he search `hello user search welcome` so he had typed more content than in mysql table so that i am trying to break it into like statement to get maximum and best result for user

Comment: what's wrong with the user typing `hello user search welcome`? If you make your sql statement like you did in your first example, it would still return your row with `Hello user search`. It would just be `Select * from table where name like '%hello%' or name like '%user%' or name like'%search%' or name like '%welcome%'; `

Comment: no it return all data in my table with `hello` `user` `search` but its ok . i need it to show result of row which contains all these words first but this not happen in my sql it show all data with `hello` `user` `search` but not with maximum match

Answer (score 0):

To just get the results as above you can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name like 'data%get%go'
```

And this will output results of this format

```
data dummy get dummy go
```